# Cannot get hours to total over 24, eg 48 hours in hh:mm:ss output

Tags: sql-server, date, dateadd

I am running a query to find out the total amount of time a user has been browsing for. Each browsing session is stored in the DB as seconds and I then sum the total seconds and convert it into `hh:mm:ss.` The problem is when I'm converting the seconds into `hh:mm:ss`. I want it to display for example `'78:20:00'` but I dont know how to get the code to total it like this. When it gets past 24 hrs the hrs column goes back to 00 because its into a day.

The query I run to convert the time can be seen below:

```
SELECT Username,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),DATEADD(SECOND,TotalTimeInSeconds,0),108) AS TotalHours
FROM #TotalSessionTime
```

Comment: Why not just return the total as a number?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT USERNAME,
       CAST(TotalTimeInSeconds / (60 * 60) AS Varchar) + ':' + 
       CAST(TotalTimeInSeconds % (60 * 60) / 60 AS Varchar) + ':' +
       CAST(TotalTimeInSeconds % (60) AS Varchar)          AS TotalHours
  FROM #TotalSessionTime
```

If you want minutes and seconds to always be two digits, you'll have to left pad them, which would make for an ugly example, but would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DECLARE @TimeInSeconds int = 123400;
DECLARE @MyDate datetime;
SELECT  @MyDate = CONVERT( DateTime, DATEADD( SECOND, @TimeInSeconds, 0))
SELECT  CONVERT(CHAR(2), (DAY( @MyDate )-1) * 24 + DATEPART(hour,@MyDate)) + ':' + CONVERT(CHAR(2), DATEPART(minute, @MyDate)) + ':' + CONVERT(CHAR(2), DATEPART(SECOND, @MyDate))
```

You'll want to left-pad the minutes and seconds with a zero to be sure it's 2-digits, though.